# BASH unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I have a BASH project for university and I have two errors that I don't understand

here is my script BASH :

```
#!/bin/bash

proc_name=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f1 | uniq`;
proc_freq=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | cut -d':' -f2 |cut -d'@' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_core=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_hyperthreading=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'siblings' | cut -d':' -f2 | uniq`;
proc_architecture=`lscpu | grep '64-bit' | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d'-' -f1`;
proc_cache_L1=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L1i' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L2=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L2' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_cache_L3=`lscpu | grep 'Cache L3' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_virtualisation=`lscpu | grep 'Virtualisation' | cut -d':' -f2 |sed "s/\ \ */\ /g"`;
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2` | tr ',' '.'`

ip_infos_addr_ipv4=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet adr:/{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`;
ip_infos_addr_ipv6=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/adr inet6:/{print $3}'`;
ip_publique_addr=`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`;
carte_reseau=`lspci |grep Ethernet | cut -d":" -f3`;


echo -e "$proc_name\n$proc_freq\n$proc_core\n$proc_hyperthreading\n$proc_architecture\n$proc_cache_L1\n$proc_cache_L2\n$proc_cache_L3\n$proc_virtualisation\n$proc_load_average\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv4\n$ip_infos_addr_ipv6\n$ip_publique_addr\n$carte_reseau" > Collecteur/collecteur_cpu_reseau.txt;
```

And here is the two errors I have :

```
./collecteur_cpu_reseau: line 17: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./collecteur_cpu_reseau: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...running `lscpu` so many times instead of just running it once and reusing the results is horribly inefficient, btw; I'd suggest rethinking your approach.

Comment: I think you have too many backticks (```) in the `proc_load_average=` line. SO highlighting helps isolate it!

Comment: ...using backticks *at all* is bad practice; the modern syntax for command substitution is `$( ... )`.

Comment: Also, any `echo` implementation where `echo -e` doesn't print `-e` on its output is breaking the POSIX standard. If you want to print a bunch of separate lines from one command, use `printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" "..."` -- that also means you aren't interpreting backslash-escapes in your data unintentionally, as opposed to the intentional ones provided as literals.

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html re: POSIX echo (particularly note the APPLICATION USAGE section).

Comment: ...also, consider all your `foo | grep | sed | tr | ...` pipelines with `foo | awk`; awk can do all the work of grep, tr, etc. in one command; and that's if you can't simplify enough to just do all the work with bash built-in primitives without any subshells or pipelines involved at all.

Comment: ...also, `ifconfig` is an ancient, unmaintained tool -- see http://serverfault.com/questions/633087/where-is-the-statement-of-deprecation-of-ifconfig-on-linux. Don't use it. `iproute2` is the modern alternative.

Answer (score 6):

```
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2` | tr ',' '.'`
```

...needs to be...

```
# remove the extra backtick
proc_load_average=`w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2 | tr ',' '.'`
```

...or better...

```
# use parens, not backticks
proc_load_average=$(w | head -1 | cut -d" " -f12 | cut -d"," -f1-2 | tr ',' '.')
```

...or better...

```
# read the content straight from procfs without the big silly pipeline
read -r loadavg_1min loadavg_5min loadavg_10min _ </proc/loadavg
echo "1-minute load average: $loadavg_1min"
```

That said, this script as a whole is unsalvageably awful.

---

For instance, consider the following alternative to all the messing around in `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
declare -A cpuinfo=( ) # create an associative array

# read line-by-line; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
while IFS=$'\t:' read -r k v || [[ $k ]]; do
  [[ $v ]] || continue
  cpuinfo[$k]=${v# } # trim leading space; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe
done </proc/cpuinfo

echo "Model name: ${cpuinfo['model name']%@*}"
echo "Model freq: ${cpuinfo['model name']#*@}"
echo "Actual frequency: ${cpuinfo['cpu MHz']}"
echo "Siblings: ${cpuinfo['siblings']}"
```

...isn't that easier? You can deploy the same strategy reading the output of a command like `lscpu` by substituting `< <(lscpu)` for `</proc/cpuinfo`.